# Can we prove that a normal surface of an extreme point of a convex subset of a simplex is a separating hyperplane?

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

Let's assume that we have a simplex $G = \{x\in R^d|\sum_{i=1}^d x_i=1, x_i\ge 0 , i = 1, 2, .., d\}$ and a polyhedral convex subset $H \subseteq G$.

Is it possible to prove that for any extremal point $x^*\in H$, the tangential surface of $x^*$ is a supporting hyperplane of $H$?

In a simple 2D case, it is somewhat trivial. However, for general high dimensional cases, it wasn't..

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "tangential surface" and "separating hyperplane"? Also, I'm not sure algebraic geometry is a relevant tag...

Comment: @MattiaTalpo Tangential surface of x is a set satisfying <x, x'> = 0. I was wrong about the separating hyperplane. It should be supporting hyperplane. Thank you.

Comment: The set satisfying $\langle x^*, x'\rangle$ is a hyperplane passing through the origin. I guess you want to consider the translate of this hyperplane that passes through $x^*$...?

Comment: I was so dumb.. Thank you so much. It (hopely) should be $\langle x^*, x \rangle = \langle x^*, x^* \rangle$

Comment: Ok, that's the translate I was talking about. Then by "extremal" I guess you mean "on the boundary of $H$"?

Comment: The 'exteremal points' that I meant are the points that are not only on the boundary on $H$ but also on the 'corners' of $H$. (making $H$ \ $x^*$ a convex set)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem to be true in higher dimension. I assume that by "supporting hyperplane" you mean that the hyperplane doesn't intersect the interior of $H$.

Look at the situation in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so you have a 2-simplex $x+y+z=1$ (a triangle). Take as $H$ the triangle on the simplex with vertices $(1,0,0), (0,0,1), (\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{6})$ (the third point is the midpoint between the barycenter and the first point). I suggest drawing a picture.

The point $p=(\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{6})$ is one of the extremal points. The equation of the plane orthogonal to the vector $\langle \frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{6} \rangle$ and that passes through $p$ is $4x+y+z=3$. Its intersection with the simplex is described by $x=\frac{2}{3}$ and $y+z=\frac{1}{3}$, and this intersects $H$ in a segment passing through its interior. For example the point $(\frac{2}{3},0,\frac{1}{3})$ is on this hyperplane and on (the boundary of) $H$.

Comment: You are right...

Answer (score 1):

[image: Figure illustrating the above counterexample]

Indeed, you are right..
The motivation behind this question is posted in 'https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563904/tangential-surface-of-an-extreme-point-of-a-convex-subset-of-a-simplex'. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem! Nice pic :)